# Hide a column when auto filter is active

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have read this [Show Excel column filter information in cells](https://superuser.com/questions/436667/show-excel-column-filter-information-in-cells) and it basically does what it is supposed to. But I want to hide and unhide column A when a filter is active. So I put in the following hide unhide code

```
Function CheckFilters(r As Range) As String

Set AWS = ActiveSheet
fstate = ""

If AWS.FilterMode Then
c = AWS.AutoFilter.Filters.Count

'go through each column and check for filters
For i = 1 To c Step 1
   If AWS.AutoFilter.Filters(i).On Then
        ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Hidden = True
        fstate = fstate & r(i).Value & ", "
   End If
Next i

'removes the last comma
fstate = Left(fstate, Len(fstate) - 2)

Else
ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Hidden = False
fstate = "Keine aktiven Filter"
End If

CheckFilters = fstate

End Function
```

But `ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Hidden = True` seems to be ignored when called from a function. When I call it from a sub it works.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808974/3789751 .

I have the following sub

```
Sub HideUnHide()
Set AWS = ActiveSheet
fstate = ""

If AWS.FilterMode Then
    c = AWS.AutoFilter.Filters.Count

    For i = 1 To c Step 1
        If AWS.AutoFilter.Filters(i).On Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i

Else
    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

And this is called from a `Worksheet_Calculate`

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Call Modul1.HideUnHide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In **VBA** *functions* are very unreliable when it come to modifying the worksheet (they are great at returning values).  You are better off using a **sub** instead.  The sub would have two parameters; The input range and the output string.

Comment: It tried it with a `SUB` but didn't know how to call that `SUB` when a filter was changed.