# Writing formulas to Excel spreadsheet using ActiveX

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, activex, labview

I'm creating an Excel spreadsheet and populating its cells programmatically using [ActiveX from inside LabVIEW](https://lavag.org/topic/12831-activex/).  I know ActiveX is old but currently it's all I have to work with.  I tried writing the formula "**=(RC[-2])/(RC[-1])**" to a column of cells where the previous 2 columns are numbers. When I open the spreadsheet the cells show the formulas rather than values.  If I select any of these cells and click inside the formula bar and then hit "Enter" the formula is immediately replaced with the value.  [This article](https://superuser.com/questions/1261444/custom-formula-not-updating) seems to imply that I am creating User-Defined Functions (UDF) which are not updated the same way as standard worksheet functions.

**Here is what I tried so far to resolve this issue without success:**

Enabling R1C1 "relative" formatting in Excel

Saving the previous 2 columns as numeric values instead of text

Formatting the formula column as "general"

Adding additional quotation marks and or parentheses

Changing the formula to "=((Value(RC[-2]))/(Value(RC[-1])))"

All 14 of the solutions [explained in this article](https://exceloffthegrid.com/why-are-excel-formulas-not-calculating/)

Writing macros to execute the commands below

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.Volatile
    Application.Calculate
    Application.CalculateFull
    ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = True
End Sub
```

The only successful workaround (not a solution) I've found is to run the macro shown below on the spreadsheet after the workbook is closed by my program.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim var As Variant

    For i = 1 To 99
        Cells(i, 8).Select
        var = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = CStr(var)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Ideally I need a solution I can carry out through ActiveX from inside LabVIEW.  This would exclude any solution using excel macros but any new suggestions, ideas or solutions will be appreciated.